# How to do code optimisation in switch statement

Tags: javascript, optimization, switch-statement

I have a one switch case with few two cases which having very least difference in code. How to declare globally to minimize the code.

Here is my code.

```
switch(clickedDataIndex){
            case A :
                var data = record.get(data1);
                var Object = {
                        'AID':AID,
                        'BID':record.get(BID),
                        'CID':record.get(CID),
                        'DId' : record.get(D1),
                }
                if(data){
                    myFunction(Object);
                }
                break
            case B:
                var data = record.get(data2);
                var Object = {
                        'AID':AID,
                        'BID':record.get(BID),
                        'CID':record.get(CID),
                        'DId' : record.get(D12),
                }
                if(data){
                    myFunction(Object);
                }
                break;
        }
```

If you notice during object creation many attributes are same. Is there any way I can avoid that.

Comment: Extract a function from those duplicated parts and call it.

Comment: Can you give a light what you suggesting

Comment: Sure, your cases would look like this: `case A: myOtherFunction(data1, 'D1'); break;`

Comment: create one parameterised function for object creation and then call that function from switch with different parameters so that it will create different objects with one function and with less code

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : Got some idea. let me try that

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks worked like charme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function to reduce the code repetition,

```
function doProcess(data, aId, bId, cId, dId){
  var data = record.get(data);
  var Object = {
      'AID': aId,
      'BID':record.get(bId),
      'CID':record.get(cId),
      'DId' : record.get(dId),
  }
  if(data) myFunction(Object);
}

switch(clickedDataIndex) {
 case 'A':
   doProcess(data1, AID, BID, CID, d1);
 break;
 case 'B':
   doProcess(data2, AID, BID, CID, D12);
 break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I used some other way but this is also working.

Answer (score 0):

Call a separate function doAction()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doAction(Data, DId)
{
    var data = record.get(Data);        
    if (data)
    {
        var Object = {
                'AID':AID,
                'BID':record.get(BID),
                'CID':record.get(CID),
                'DId' : record.get(DId),
        }

        myFunction(Object);
    }
}

switch(clickedDataIndex)
{
    case A :
        doAction(data1, D1);
        break;
    case B:
        doAction(data2, D12);       
        break;
}
</script>
```